# How to W3C validate React app HTML output

Tags: html, reactjs, validation, jsx, w3c

Does anyone has any approach how to run you React app through W3C validator to discover if any HTML is invalid? Thanks

[W3C HTML validation for React JSX files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650295/w3c-html-validation-for-react-jsx-files) is duplicate but was asked ~ 4 years ago. Maybe some new tools available these days?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [W3C HTML validation for React JSX files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650295/w3c-html-validation-for-react-jsx-files)

Comment: Partially, as this question was asked almost 4 years ago I would like to hear if anyone has any alternative or new ways. Maybe some new tools on the market?